# Submitting file with jquery / ajax / php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, forms, http-post

I'm having a problem with my ajax file for submission. There doesn't appear to be anything submitted (neither variables nor the files) to the receiving php file.

This is my form:

```
<form id="ProtocolForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <input name="ProtocolName" type="hidden" value="sdfsdf">
   <input name="ProtocolType" type="hidden" value="Image">        
   <input name="name_major" id="name_major" type="text">
   <input name="name_minor" id="name_minor" type="text">
   <input name="creator" id="creator" type="text">
   <input name="File" class="File" id="File" type="file">
   <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Save Protocol">
</form>
```

This is my js code:

```
 $(document).on( "submit", "#ProtocolForm", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var form = $('form')[0];  
        var formData = new FormData(form)

          $.ajax({
            url: "_save_protocol.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:  formData,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend : function()
            {
                alert('before send:' + $('form').serialize());
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                if(data=='invalid')
                {
                    alert('Invalid file');
                }
                else
                {                         
                    alert('Response:' + data);                     
                }
            },
            error: function(e) 
            {
                alert('Error '+ e);

            }          
            });


    });
```

When the form is submitted the alert I can see all the variables serialized in the beforeSend function. However when I try to access the variables in the php file they are all blank. $_POST is blank as is $_FILES. What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does the form actually submit?  Check your console - do you get a 404/500 error on the request?

Comment: The form submits as far as I can tell and I can see the output from the receiving php file in the response.

Comment: Then do `var_dump( $_REQUEST )` in your php to see if the post data is actually being sent correctly

Comment: Is this the only form on the page? `$('form')[0]` will select the first form on the page, not necessarily this one. Use `var form = this` instead.

Comment: the var_dump doesnt show the form data - any idea why it isnt being sent correctly ?

Comment: This is the only form on the page,

Comment: In your ajax call, pass `$('form').serialize())` for data instead of `formData`

Comment: When I change the method to "GET" and pass $('form').serialize() for data it works. However when the method is set to "POST" it passes nothing.

Comment: What is ``new FormData(form)`` ? Forget about it and pass ``$('form').serialize())`` to your request: ``data:  $('form').serialize()),``. You're passing different object to your http request, and displaying different object in your beforeSend callback method. Do what @WillardSolutions wrote above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem; The issue was not the ajax but rather the server side of things. php.ini max_post_size was not set appropriately and the server was not handling the post requests properly as a result. It's fixed and working now.

Reading some of the other questions around the topic on this site makes me think that this is a rather common problem - especially to those that are on a shared hosting service like myself. Hope this helps others.